# How to convert field character in mysql when Incorrect string value?

Tags: mysql

This is my create table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `owner` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET gbk NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

There are already some historical data in table.
I want to change the character of **name** field from **gbk** to **utf8**
When i executed this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE owner MODIFY COLUMN name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

return **error message**:

> ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xA3\xA0' for column
>   `test`.`owner`.`name` at row 3047064

checked this row data:

```
MariaDB [sd]> select * from owner limit 3047063,1;
+-------------+------------+
| id          | name       |
+-------------+------------+
| 3047945     | 欧文?      |
+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.402 sec)
```

I think the problem should appear on this `?`.

There are many other similar data, how can I handle it quickly?
Can be deleted, can be updated.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77154/76803

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved!
Using `HEX` function.

```
select * from owner where hex(name) like '%A3A0'
```